# Silverlight: How to set a ListBoxItem as selected only when a child control is clicked?

Tags: silverlight, listbox

In a Silveright view, I have a `ListBox`, and each `ListBoxItem` within it contains a Hyperlink. By default, clicking anywhere on a `ListBoxItem` will highlight that item as selected. What I'd like to do is override the default selection behaviour, and make the Hyperlink inside each `ListBoxItem` act as the selection 'handle' for its parent, so that the `ListBoxItem` is only selected when the Hyperlink is clicked, while clicking anywhere else on the `ListBoxItem` has no effect. Is this possible and if so how could I achieve it?

The `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".65*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>                               
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding UploadDate,
                        Converter={StaticResource DateDescriptionConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                   Text="{Binding HistoryStatus}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="DisplayDocument"
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                 Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="View"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <Interactions:CallMethodAction
                                TargetObject="{Binding Path=DataContext,
                                   ElementName=DocumentViewPanel}"
                                MethodName="ViewDocumentButtonClick"/>
                        </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                </HyperlinkButton>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

To put this in some context, the contents of the `ListBox` is a list of documents, and clicking the Hyperlink loads the document in to a separate pane. With the default selection behaviour, by clicking the background of an item in the `ListBox`, the item can display as being selected without its corresponding document actually being loaded.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Didn't want to put this as an answer in case it's not what you're looking for....but you could omit the SelectedState from the VisualStateManager of the control template and set your HyperlinkButton's `ClickMode` to `Press` which should provide the effect you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you pick another `control` from the range of available base controls: I think the `ItemsControl` would be a good fit.

Why?
The `ListBox` is made to display a list of items and whenever you click anywhere on an item it will be selected. That's its purpose.
Apparently you don't want that - I'm not even sure you want the concept of "selection" at all.

As far as I understood: You want a visual list of items; each offering at least one action you can invoke for that very item and you want a visual indication that you have performed an associated action for an item.

Let's try to do this with an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                ....
                <Border
                   Background="Blue"
                   x:Name="DocumentDisplayed_Indicator"
                   Opacity="0"/>
                <HyperlinkButton ...>
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <Interactions:CallMethodAction
                                    TargetObject="{Binding Path=DataContext,
                                    ElementName=DocumentViewPanel}"
                                    MethodName="ViewDocumentButtonClick"/>
                            <SetPropertyAction
                                    TargetName="DocumentDisplayed_Indicator"
                                    Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                </HyperlinkButton>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: The ItemsControl in Silverlight does not have an ItemContainerStyle property as the ListBox does. Without it, the grid inside each item is not stretching to fill the container and the content is squashed to the left. Is there an ItemsControl alternative to the ListBox's ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: @Lee D: The `ItemsControl` uses an instance of `ContentControl` per each item, so setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment` on that `ContentControl` should solve it. How to set it? Try to set it on the `ItemsControl`, maybe it is propagated to all the items' ContentControls. If you want to know for sure, load `Blend` and inspect the `DefaultTemplate` for `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, replacing the ListBox with ItemsControl has got me most of the way to where I need to be. I solved the layout problems by changing the widths of the grid columns.